# How to select or pass value into hidden type for drop down picklist on website?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

[very new at selenium and HTML]

I want to select a drop down from a website. The `type` is hidden. I just want to pass or select either `male` or `female` from the drop down or pass it into the `value` variable, how would I do this?

I used the inspect element in chrome to determine the two lines below are the ones required to select a value.

```
<div class="Select has-value is-clearable is-searchable Select--single">
    <input name="customer.gender" type="hidden" value="female">
```

I got the xpath from chrome and tried to pass a value but did not work:

```
gender = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/span[2]/div/input")
gender.send_keys('male')
```

The entire HTML of the above `div` element is:

```
<div class="Select has-value is-clearable is-searchable Select--single">
    <input name="customer.gender" type="hidden" value="female">
    <div class="Select-control">
        <span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-5--value">
            <div class="Select-value">
                <span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-5--value-item">Female</span>
            </div>
            <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
                <input aria-activedescendant="react-select-5--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" 
                    aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;">
                <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 14px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div>
            </div>
        </span>
        <span aria-label="Clear value" class="Select-clear-zone" title="Clear value">
            <span class="Select-clear">×</span>
        </span>
        <span class="Select-arrow-zone">
            <span class="Select-arrow"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

edit:

HTML from where I click on the drop down without any values selected:

```
<div class="Select is-searchable Select--single">
    <div class="Select-control">
        <span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-5--value">
            <div class="Select-placeholder">Select:</div>
            <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
                <input aria-activedescendant="react-select-5--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false"
                    aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;">
                <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; 
                            overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 14px; 
                            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; 
                            font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div>
            </div>
        </span>
        <span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

edit2:

HTML from value selected in drop down

```
<div class="Select has-value is-clearable is-searchable Select--single">
    <input name="customer.gender" type="hidden" value="male">
    <div class="Select-control">
        <span class="Select-multi-value-wrapper" id="react-select-5--value">
            <div class="Select-value">
                <span class="Select-value-label" role="option" aria-selected="true" id="react-select-5--value-item">Male</span>
            </div>
            <div class="Select-input" style="display: inline-block;">
                <input aria-activedescendant="react-select-5--value" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" 
                    aria-owns="" role="combobox" value="" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 5px;">
                <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; height: 0px; 
                            overflow: scroll; white-space: pre; font-size: 14px; 
                            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; 
                            font-style: normal; letter-spacing: normal; text-transform: none;"></div>
            </div>
        </span>
        <span aria-label="Clear value" class="Select-clear-zone" title="Clear value">
            <span class="Select-clear">×</span>
        </span>
        <span class="Select-arrow-zone"><span class="Select-arrow"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You did not show the complete/correct HTML code of the dropdown, I don't see the HTML code for option `Male`

Comment: @yong the option only changes when I select it from the drop down. I don’t see it anywhere else in the code. The value changes as soon as I click the button.

Comment: @yong do you think I am still missing something ?

Comment: Please give a screenshot of your dropdown.  Does the dropdown comes from React component?

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdown is a React Component, I get example from this [site](https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/).

```
// click on dropdown to expand options
dirver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='react-select-5--value']/..").click();

// choose option
dirver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//span[@id='react-select-5--value']/../.." +
    "//div[@role='option'][text()='%s']".format("Male")).click();
```

The dropdown options inside node: `<div class="Select-menu-outer">`, this node is attached to the page after you click on the dropdown, and de-attached from page after you choose one option.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the response. my apologies got caught up in work. However your response it is not working for me. I get error can not find element from the first line of code:

i set it up like this `gender = dirver.find_element_by_css_selector(
  "input[name='customer.gender'] + div.Select-control")
  .click();` `gender=dirver.find_element_by_xpath(
  "//div[input[@name='customer.gender']]//div[@role='option'][text()='%s']".format("Male"))
  .click();`

Comment: please try the css locator `input[name='customer.gender'] + div.Select-control` manually on browser to see it can find expect element or not.

Comment: I did inspect element on the drop down and searched for the line did not find it.

Comment: I made a edit with the drop down element without any values selected.

Comment: I found `div.Select-control` in the HTML inspect element.

Comment: Please double check your given HTML in your question is correct. And your given HTML code does not include the HTML code of the options of dropdown.

Comment: the second html I provided is the one without any drop down selected. I went with this because when I select a drop down value it only appears when selected.

Comment: added HTML for when option is selected